# read Lucene index without server

Tags: javascript, lucene, client-side

I would read Lucene index client-side, ie without any server.

The index folder is in local. In fact, I have the folder of a website, inside there is a folder containing several docs(xml) and the lucene index.
In the doc, there is elements like

```
 <link ref="A-B-C">a link</link>
```

and in the lucene index, A-B-C refer to a path like _hat_A-B-C.xml. 
So I would read Lucene index with JS or other languages client-side.

I find [lucene.js](https://github.com/dennycd/lucene.js) but I think it use Node.js and so we must use a server.

Which tool can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if JS running in someone's web browser could access your Lucene index without a server making it available.

If you want an easy server solution, Solr and ElasticSearch are both good options that expose Lucene to remote clients, with web-based APIs you could call directly from client-side Javascript.

Or you could send the JS calls to whatever you're using to serve the HTML pages, and have that use Lucene/Solr/ES/etc. behind the scenes.

[Source](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-query-a-lucene-index-from-JavaScript-no-server-or-jvm-td4019318.html)